# What's the trick to the "Catch" minigame in Tomodachi Life?

Tags: tomodachi-life

What's the trick to the "Catch" minigame in Tomodachi Life? Usually the item that the Mii drops bounces off my hand. What's the trick to it

Answer (score 1):

According to a post on [Game FAQS](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/643013-tomodachi-life/69519749)

> Depending on the size of the item... some things are easier to catch.
>   If I had to provide tips:
>
> -Before the Mii drops the item, tap on your screen to get a feel for where you have to catch it. (Notice the finger and thumb)
>
> -Turn off the sound
>
> -Make sure the 3ds isn't right in your face. Keep it further away.
>
> -I'm sure it varies for people, but I prefer staring at the top screen while waiting for the item to drop. Others may simply rely on their
>   peripheral vision and stare at the bottom screen.